# Javascript: "Cannot read property "name" of undefined" error at native javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm working in a Chrome extension. At some point, in a script called `CLAWS_Sem_Imagens_Script.js`, I send a message from an Iframe inside the page to my background-page with the following line:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"execution order",sendToContentScript:true, data:"show"});
```

It works most of the times. However, **sometimes**, javascript throws the error `Cannot read property "name" of undefined`, at the line `316` of `@extensions::messaging:`

```
if (port.name != kNativeMessageChannel)...
```

The full call stack is:

```
sendMessageImpl @ extensions::messaging:316
(anonymous function) @ extensions::runtime:115
target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
(anonymous function) @ extensions::binding:57
target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
(anonymous function) @ extensions::binding:385
enviaPalavraAoBackgroundPageImagem @ CLAWS_Sem_Imagens_Script.js:66
```

Do someone has any guess? Please ask me for any additional info you need.

EDIT: My manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://google.com.br/",
    "http://localhost/*",
    "https://localhost/*"
  ],


 "background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["CLAWS_Content_Script.js", "jquery.js", "Caixas_De_Texto_Dos_Botoes.js"],
      "css": ["CLAWS_Content_Script_CSS.css"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]

    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
        "iframe.html",
        "icon.png",
        "Caixas_De_Texto_Dos_Botoes.js",
        "search.png"
  ]


}
```

Comment: Are you using an event page (`"persistent": false`)? Where is that error displayed (webpage console or background page console)? And just in case add your manifest.json to the question.

Comment: @wOxxom no, just a background page! The error is displayed at the consolse we see when we open the developer tools - I make no idea of how we call it. And the manifest is added : )

Comment: First option! I didn't know this second one, for saying the truth!

Comment: @wOxxOm think I found out, and it was really a stupidness of mine if it is true. When I tried to send the message, the extensions was disabled (though the page wasn't updated, so I didn't realize it). I'll try to confirm that!

Comment: But just in behalf of curiosity, how do I access this other console?

Comment: Weird, can't find that link!

Comment: Enable `[x] Developer mode` on the top of that page.

Comment: @MrGuliarte, what is the solution here exactly?  I'm having same issue.  Only happens if I send a message immediately after inline installation of the chrome extension for the first time.

Comment: @That1guyoverthr I don't know if it's your case, but if you are in one page and you disable the extension (going at chrome://extensions and unmarking the box aside it), but remain on that page, the extension apparently continues to work, but it's background page gets disabled...hope it helps!

Comment: @MrGuliarte plesae can you add your solution as an answer below, that will make it easier for people to find the solution, thanks and thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 2):

This can also occur if you reload the extension but not the page with injected script. Reloading the page solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the error was occurring because the extension was disabled (chrome://extensions -> unmark the check box), and then the background page was disabled, even with the extension aparently working. Regards!